# Проблемы с кодировкой при загрузке с ftp-сервера

Tags: c#, кодировка, ftp

На ftp-сервере есть файлы с кириллическими названиями, большинство из них адекватно себя ведут под utf-8. Но файлы в одной из папок недоступны по нормальным названиям при загрузке с использованием `WebClient`. Тем не менее, при сборе списка файлов (через `FtpWebRequest` и `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory`) имена отображаются нормально если указать кодировку при чтении `StreamReader` как `System.Text.Encoding.Default`. Как же мне указать кодировку чтобы я мог загрузить их на ПК? Default, utf-8 - не работают, ошибка доступа к файлу, аля "файл с таким отсутствует". Без кириллицы в названии - проблем нет

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = @"ftp://...";
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "pass");
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(""); // Вот только какую?
    //...
}
```

Comment: Как же мне указать кодировку чтобы я мог загрузить их на ПК* Прошу прощения, опечатался

Comment: Если опечатались - надо опечатку исправлять правкой, а не комментарием.

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `Encoding` используется не для имен файлов, а для их содержимого. Менять надо не это свойство, а передаваемый адрес.

Вообще говоря, кодировку надо исправлять на стороне ftp-сервера. Но если менять ее там - не вариант, то можно воспользоваться традиционным в таких случаях костылем "прочитать строку как есть, а потом передать обратно в неизменном виде".

Иными словами - попробуйте получить с сервера список файлов в других кодировках, после чего попытайтесь скачать получившуюся "абракадабру".

Еще один возможный вариант - попробуйте закодировать русские символы через [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx). Во втором случае также можно попытаться по-перебирать кодировку.